# JQuery File Upload Before Send Ping Server for existing file

Tags: backbone.js, jquery-events, jquery-file-upload, backbone-events

I am new to Jquery File Upload and it works great.  But I am wondering if anyone knows of a good way to block sending the upload until a GET request can be sent to *verify that the file does not already exist*?

I am using backbone.js and have already tried attaching an interception to both the submit form event and the file input change event.  **Both are bypassed.**

Currently looks something like this:

```
  events: {
        'change form.upload-file input': 'checkExist'
    },

    checkExist: function (e) {
        return false;
    },

    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this);

        this.$('.upload-file').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'PUT',
            add: this.add,
            progress: this.progress,
            done: this.done,
            fail: this.fail,
            always: this.always
        });

        return __super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by just having a list of the files on hand and stopping the xhr if included

```
beforeSend : function(xhr, opts){
                var q = 'Do you want to replace ' + opts.files[0].name + '?';
                if( that.checkExist(xhr, opts) && !window.confirm(q))  {
                    xhr.abort();
                }
            },
```

It would still be nice to know a way to do this async.